# java EnumSet, incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, generics, enums, enumset

I have a the below method which returns a enum set containing all of the elements of `Types`:

```
@Override
public EnumSet<?> groupTypes() {
    return EnumSet.allOf(Types.class);
}
```

And the `Types` is an `enum` like below:

```
public enum Types implements GroupType {
    ASG;
}
```

The `GroupType` interface is:

```
 public interface GroupType extends NamedType {

 }
```

The `NamedType` interface:

```
public interface NamedType {

    String name();

}
```

When compile, I got the below error:

```
    error: incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
return EnumSet.allOf(Types.class);
                        ^

equality constraints: Types
    upper bounds: Enum<CAP#1>,Enum<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Enum<E> declared in method <E>allOf(Class<E>)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Enum<CAP#1> from capture of ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Error: incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible
>   bounds return EnumSet.allOf(Types.class);

is telling you what is the problem. One way to resolve is to change the signature like this

```
public EnumSet<? extends NamedType> groupTypes() {
        return EnumSet.allOf(Types.class);
    }
```

or you can just assign `EnumSet.allOf(Types.class)` to a variable and then there is no need to change the method signature like this

```
public EnumSet<?> groupTypes() {
    EnumSet<Types> typeses = EnumSet.allOf(Types.class);
    return typeses;
}
```